# termios.h How to use special characters

Tags: c, termios

I have a terminal that is set in ~(ICANON) mode and wondering how I can use the data that I get for the backspace (which is ^?) so I can send a putchar('\b') to the console to go back one space.

EDIT:

```
struct termios new;
newt.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON);
tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &newt); // Set the console to send each char straight away.

char c;
while ((c = getchar()) != '\n){
   // If the backspace key is pressed, the symbols ^? appear on the screen. How do I
   // Interpret the backspace to send back a '\b' char to the screen. I don't want the ^?
   // to appear on the screen when the backspace is pressed but rather the cursor move one
   // space to the left.
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Please rephrase your question, currently it's too opaque. I can't catch what is e.g. "the data that I get for the backspace". Also I guess you are mixing input and output issues. What code is used for backspace, and how to send something to make concrete change in viewed state, is defined for a terminal in capability database (`termcap`, `terminfo`). Do you try to repeat `curses` library activity by yourself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the terminal in raw mode (`~ICANON`), the <kbd>BkSp</kbd> key will output the byte `0x7f`, which is not interpreted as a backspace by the terminal. (This is so that it can be distinguished from the keystroke <kbd>^H</kbd>.) If you want this keystroke to be interpreted by the terminal as a backspace, you will need to:

1. Disable echo on the terminal (`~ECHO`), then
2. Echo back most characters as they are input, but echo `0x7f` as `0x08` (`\b`). (You will also probably need to echo `\n` as `\r\n`.)